# How to set pointer fields in a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct

I am really confused with structs in C. I am trying to make an array of words which I store in pointer. I then set the args field of line to the pointer. I have the following code:

```
typedef struct line{
    char *args[MAX_INPUT];
    struct line *next;
} line;


void read_line(){
    line l1;
    char *pointer = (char *)malloc(1024);
    l1.args = pointer;
}
```

Comment: The error I get is that: array type 'char *[1024]' is not assignable.

Comment: You assign a pointer to an array of pointers. Is your line an array of strings? Then you have to allocate memory separately for each string. Or is it one string? Then you do not need an array.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], make sure it's both minimal and complete. Also, instead of adding bits as comment, [edit] your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @DYZ I am trying to read a line, break it up into single words, store each word in an array of strings and then set the field of the struct line (args) to the array of strings.

Comment: `pointer` is not an array of strings. It is a pointer to _one_ string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break a line into words, you need a loop:

```
void read_line(){
    line l1;
    // Some kind of a loop: while or for - with a loop variable i
    // For each fragment:
    {        
        char *pointer = malloc(1024);            
        l1.args[i] = pointer;
        // Here, copy the next fragment into l1.args[i]
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration you used `char *args[MAX_INPUT];` is not what you want. If you want to declare a pointer, then you should do it like this;

```
char *args;
```

And then, if you want to use this pointer as an array with size of MAX_INPUT, you can do it like this;

```
args = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INPUT);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and the cast `(char *)` is not needed.

Comment: Change last line to `args = malloc(sizeof *args * MAX_INPUT);`